# Databricks SQL Variables and if/else task in workflow

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql, databricks-workflows

I have 2 tasks in databricks job workflow first task is of type SQL and SQL task is query.In that query I've declared 2 variables and SET the values by running query.e.g:

```
DECLARE VARIABLE max_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01' ;
SET VARIABLE max_timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from TableA );
select max_timestamp ;
```

Can I pass this max_timestamp variable to the next if/else task to check if it is null or is there any value in this variable and pass that value of max_timestamp to another task. or is there any workaround to do this? I want to use sql warehouse for this.

I created a sql task and assign max timestamp value from subquery to the sql variable and also created if/else task and in condition I've added {{tasks.[task_name].values.[value_name]}}, but the job throw below error on the if/else task.

run failed with error message

Failed to resolve references: Task value referenced by 'tasks.task_name.values.max_timestamp' was not found.

Query based dropdown list option in databricks sql editor will execute the query multiple times if I use the variable at multiple places in a big sql query ? If yes then it will be executing query to max_timestamp everytime I refer in the query.

Comment: `DECLARE` not supported in sql warehouse. It is only supported in databricks runtime 14.1 and above. So you need to use databricks cluster with sql notebook.

Comment: Are you ok with using combination of sql and python in single notebook using db runtime 14.1?

Comment: because  `{{tasks.[task_name].values.[value_name]}}` supported only in python notebook

Comment: @JayashankarGS, I can use any method available, but I want to execute queries only sql warehouse and for parameters I can use databricks clusters. Is there any way around for this?

Comment: @JayashankarGS can I save sql statements in .sql file using python and upload it in workspace/Repos and run using sql warehouse? or using python program can I create a databricks sql objects (queries, Alerts) and paste the sql statements in it and upload it to workspace using python?

Answer (score 0):

**`DECLARE`** is not supported in SQL warehouses; it is supported only in Databricks runtime 14.1 and above. Even though you use Databricks runtime 14.1 and above, you can not use the dynamic values `{{tasks.[task_name].values.[value_name]}}` because it is supported in Python notebooks and should be initialized using `dbutils` like below.

`dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set(key = 'name', value = 'Some User')`

So, you need to use a combination of SQL query type jobs and Python notebooks to check conditions in your case.

In your first task of type **SQL**, run your query and create a table using the results as given below.

**Query**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE maxTimestamp
AS SELECT MAX(customer_short_code) AS max_timestamp FROM table_name;

SELECT * FROM maxTimestamp;
```

This will create a table `maxTimestamp` and retrieve this result in the next task using a Python notebook and set task values.

**Code** in the notebook which creates task values.

```py
ts = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM maxTimestamp").collect()[0][0]
print(ts)
dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set(key = 'max_timestamp', value = ts)
```

Make sure you create a table and retrieve table data in the same database.

Next, add an **If/else** task like you have previously.
There you add this `{{tasks.createTaskvalue.values.max_timestamp}}` dynamic value for condition checking.

Below is the flow diagram.

[image]

Here, **tst** is a notebook used for setting task values, and next `task2` is a condition check.